# Newsletter module plugin

Tags: plugin

When the customer signs the newsletter on the homepage of my store, I would like to check the email before allowing it to be saved to the mysql table.

In my test editing the file "NewActio.php" in "vendor \ magento \ module_newsletter \ controller \ subscriber \", I can make it work, but now I need it done by a plugin instead of editing the native Magento file

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This in native functionality. Go to Stores > Configuration > CUSTOMERS > Newsletter > Need to Confirm and set it to Yes.

Comment: Thank you for your attention!

I apologize, my explanation was very elusive.

What I need to do is manipulate the email before it is saved to the table.

In my test editing the file "NewActio.php" in "vendor \ magento \ module_newsletter \ controller \ subscriber \", I can make it work, but now I need it done by a plugin instead of editing the native Magento file.